# Azure redirect link, can't decode token with the SSO login

Tags: flutter, azure, single-sign-on

I'm trying to do a login with SSO for a Flutter web app. Everything works, Azure redirects to the link i configure in Azure portal with the correct strucure (

```
http://localhost:64914/home#code=0.AQIAQqIUuRjnO0SkfGtMZJ2MCrlkWETIT8RIoAqLKCqBcTsCAAA.AgABAAIAAAAmoFfGtYxvRrNriQdPKIZ-AgDs_wUA9P-cOC8H93goXEnnuIOZptwTtULf9xJsHT1SkQNqruSFVdGzeU-XBy-GoEQCeaknlLapNbVUcFmRP8t9_WrQbZIaswC3VO6dZJMbxkO2qhW4mZ0bvT9sCxehPPEcKL8INIgboVVUxMGYXlhBw3qiyhFYMewLlSoC4ODsMoMobr3mJiGtLtm1hc0amr8nHxsjx2RloPCEae0WPZRpAfb5Ic61YgHwUnZp6BmzXCpe0hc6Ch8-w-7wa_6KakgWh73MsqAeVkR-do9mIE1jyRp-BAQ-rP7iRS9kL2PN93ATQWqtTFnimfxMd_FmS7u3CKbrbHQBxNuOxYhi-z3WUa0S1sPe6CE5ogjRYi_NkO6iqQw9TWyzf1mDxTlIkLIrIUgJDSQYIQsiMkP7xdgXyb1FB33KGWeg5q7pmN7IC9oH3sw4s2BdZBaWV4hEwYj-2uPXyBhAABeZuMbkfWVNAGxGucxwvrlUyiwZton2Hgm1mvLaRiuQmqftAb93gBSDKd6kgRA-2kRduee7n0JSMcp9R0OdDDwBAxXPfaxiMHb2ss3yFBLFCEuqZRoavfFhIVjeO5OqOYgK-mXQJdnMhETH8yNBCh7bmVtxBbOKt3-XwCW2w6XyJX7HpgEIaNeF93gfONzHgWukKEYhcCi5wvRwdsn_FwY2IhY-b7HuooqZeowVzY9VV2WAzifyJv0ZW-B3Z-rwoTf1g2tMeQIiXGcuOXzJy1JZcB-1287NHSEjNfxvJIP1tSPiZA6h0WOWCAZ9hVKA5mKqQ_MWwy-E4mtTQmqcKqz9Z5zTeWGAI0_Tv2EGCaW9BzXoE5wVuwcmvhxB1KfJZj2iKz5_ysv5FFe_ZblIxsQ2knwSZVK8aX3JUicpcWyiutLVtFSow6jZBPEBRhCRX_w52Gfjp9P8ulQ&client_info=eyJ1aWQiOiJmM2Y1OGUxMS1mZTBkLTRlN2UtYTM0Yi1mNDE0YWFhZjYxMDAiLCJ1dGlkIjoiYjkxNGEyNDItZTcxOC00NDNiLWE0N2MtNmI0YzY0OWQ4YzBhIn0&state=eyJpZCI6IjU0YmI0ZmRjLTliNWYtNGJlMy04MDVhLWZhNmVmZjkzYjYwOCIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QifX0%3d&session_state=6e83c181-fa2e-4093-9991-6fa326677c2c)
```

but i can not decode this link in my flutter app. Even if it's localhost or another redirect link that is pointing to my fronted app, it's like the fragment params is not seen at all. When i grab the link in the app is giving me everything before #

Comment: Can you provide your code what you have tried and error details.

Comment: Are you using nodejs for building flutter web app?

Comment: i have no errors in my app, on Azure side everything works but my problem is that i can not get the code from url in order to generate the access token

Comment: No, i m not using NodeJs. for the backend i link directly to GCP

Comment: Why is Azure redirecting to a URL with a fragment? It would normally redirect to URL?code=xxx. Did you configure your app as a single page app (SPA) in Azure? Can you update the question with screenshots of how you configured the App Registration (redacted).